# No puedo seleccionar un botón en js

Tags: javascript, botón

Mi problema viene al intentar seleccionar el botón de mi html en mi archivo js, que no entiendo por qué pero devuelve un valor null, como si no lo cogiera vaya. Es la enésima vez que reviso código y debería funcionar, pero siempre que trato de clickar el botón no funciona. En el código selecciono el botón con su id bajo el nombre de searchBtn. Le agrego un event listener que con el evento click ejecuta mi función, que lleva como parámetro el valor de mi input (searchTerm). Agradecería mucho algo de visión en este asunto porque me trae de cabeza de hace días. Gracias y un saludo!

```
const searchTerm = document.getElementById('input');
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("buscar");


const fetchPokemon = async pokemon => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    renderPokemon(data);
}


const renderPokemon = (data) => {
    const sprite = data.sprites.front_default;
    const name = data.name;
    const id = data.id.toString();

    const div = document.getElementById('container');
    const pokeName = document.createElement('div');
    const pokeImage = document.createElement('img');
    const pokeId = document.createElement('div');

    pokeName.classList.add('pokeName');
    pokeImage.classList.add('pokeImage');
    pokeId.classList.add('pokeId');

    div.appendChild(pokeName);
    div.appendChild(pokeImage);
    div.appendChild(pokeId);

    pokeName.textContent = name;
    pokeImage.setAttribute('src', sprite);
    pokeId.textContent = `#${id.padStart(3, '0')}`;
    

    const width = 60;
    const height = 32;

    pokeImage.setAttribute('width', width);
    pokeImage.setAttribute('height', height);
}

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click!');
});
```

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Pokédex</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Pokédex</h1>
    <h3>&copy;alperonoberto 2022</h3>


    <div class="search">
        <input type="text" name="pokemon" id="input" placeholder="Busque un Pokemon...">
        <button id="buscar">buscar</button>
    </div>

    
    <div class="nextprev">
        <button id="prev"><-</button>
        <button id="next">-></button>
    </div>

    <div id="container">

    </div>

    
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: Tienes errores tipográficos en tu `html`. No puedes poner los símbolos `<` y `>` de manera literal porque forman parte de la sintaxis de html. Para escribir `<` debes usar `&lt;` y para escribir `>` debes usar `&gt;`. ¿El editor que usas no te señala eso como error?

Comment: cierto, acabo de corregir el error. De todas maneras, el problema viene en el botón de buscar. A la hora de coger el javascript la id del botón y almacenarlo en la variable searchBtn devuelve null. De todas maneras, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El error venía a la hora de cargar los elementos en mi HTML. Al declarar en mi index.html la fuente del archivo js, lo hacía en el , error grave dado que los elementos del html no siempre cargaban antes que el script, por tanto el botón que quería coger en el js no se encontraba dado que no se había cargado todavía en el DOM. Un simple  o cargar el script al final del body bastaba para solucionarlo.